# QueryOver child collection from parent

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I have this 2 objects:

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual int Poid { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Child> Child { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public virtual int Poid { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name {get; set;}    
}
```

I want to use NHibernet QueryOver API to get a child based on the Parent Id and Child Id, That's mean something like give me the child with Id = x belonging to the parent with Id = y.

I tried something like this:

```
return Session.QueryOver<Parent>().Where(p => p.Poid == y)
                .JoinQueryOver(p => p.WishesLists)
                .Where(c => c.Poid == x)
                .SingleOrDefault<Child>();
```

But I'm getting an exception that is not possible to convert an object of type Child to Parent.

How is the correct form to QueryOver starting with a Parent Entity but return a Child Entity?

Comment: Does `Child` have a mapped reference to parent? That is, is `Child.Parent` available?

Comment: Thanks for reply, but not it doesn't have, child don't don't have to know about the parent. Anywhere I solved with the answer of @jamie-ide down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is possible with QueryOver, I worked at it for a while without getting anywhere. It is possible with LINQ:

```
var child = session.Query<Parent>()
                   .Where(p => p.Poid == y)
                   .SelectMany(p => p.WishesLists)
                   .SingleOrDefault(c => c.Poid == x);
```

I strongly prefer the LINQ syntax over QueryOver.

See also [NH-3176](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3176)

Comment: Thanks @Jamie I tried with QueryOver with no success also but I realize that is more easy with LINQ syntax and your answer help me. Thanks